# How to set up a secure VirtualBox VM in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-permissions

What's a good way to make a Debian VM reasonably safe for online banking if running Windows as a host system?

I thought of the following points:

- normal usage of the Windows system as a restricted user X (I think its called "User" in Windows)
- Setup and Run secure VM by starting Virtual Box as another restricted user Y
- Allow write access of secure VM storage file only as user Y
- run reasonably secure browser setup in vm (no javascript, no flash)

Does that sound good and what would you suggest to do further?

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Malware accessing your account? In theory, the host system could have a keylogger running which grabs your username and password, even if entered in a VM. Network attackers? The data is still going out in the same way. People with access to your physical machine? In short, what does it have to be safe from?

Comment: Additionally, disabling flash and JS isn't ever a workable solution - most bank sites use it for virtual keyboards, image views etc. But more importantly, as @Matthew said, what are you trying to protect from?

Comment: Also use a vpn and always ensure a strong https connection.

Answer (score 1):

The VM is only as secure as the machine it's running on.

The proper setup is a clean install from verified media, and then doing all untrusted, day-to day activity in a VM. And secure business in another, clean VM

That way you have an installed machine. For simple things, just make a linux live USB and work from that.

Comment: How is "Do risky stuff in a VM" not a VM solution? Then the banking could be done on the host as well, at least you get some added security.

Comment: Doing risky stuff in a VM is absolutely the right solution.  Your previous answer, before you just edited it, said "Boot from a Linux Live USB stick", which is not what was being asked for.

Comment: I moved it to the bottom; you're right my recommendation did not strictly match the answer. So i made it the secondary option, however my original post did answer the question. Just not in the first sentence.